# Free online mathematical software

Tags: big-list, math-software, experimental-mathematics

What are the best free user-friendly alternatives to Mathematica and Maple available online?

I used [Magma online calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) a few times for computational algebra issues, and was very much satisfied, even though the calculation time there was limited to $60$ seconds.

Very basic computations can be carried out with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). What if one is interested in integer relation detection or integration involving special functions, asymptotic analysis etc?

Thank you in advance.

---

**Added**: It would be nice to provide links in the answers so that the page becomes easily usable. I would also very much appreciate short summary on what a particular software is suitable/not suitable for. For example, Magma is in my opinion useless for doing the least numerics.

Comment: Are you only interested in symbolic computation, or also numerical computation?

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong: Numerical computation as well.

Comment: @O.L.: There is a nice [*comparison of CAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) that is worth exploring. Some do and don't have online versions. Maxima has an online version. Also, there is Mathics, which is a mathematica like clone and it has an online variant, although it obviously does not have the power of mathematica. Regards

Comment: @O.L.  I favourited this question before while posting an answer below. :++)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I propose [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/). In my opinion it is the best free open-source mathematics software system.

Comment: Just to add, you can use it for free online in two ways:

[Sage cell](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/) which is the most similar to the magma calculator.

And [Sage notebook](http://www.sagenb.org/) which is similar to mathematica's notebook interface.

Comment: @VelvetThunder Is knowledge of / experience with Java syntax essential?

Answer (score 8):

Under development but already working very nicely is [Sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html), a symbolic math package for Python.

The usage is similar to other math software, there is even a [live](http://live.sympy.org/) version available. A session might look like the following:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols('x')
>>> f = cos(x)
>>> f.series()
1 - x**2/2 + x**4/24 + O(x**6)
>>> f.series(n=12)
1 - x**2/2 + x**4/24 - x**6/720 + x**8/40320 - x**10/3628800 + O(x**12)
>>> latex(f.series(n=12))
```

$1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{24} - \frac{x^{6}}{720} + \frac{x^{8}}{40320} - \frac{x^{10}}{3628800} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{12}\right)$

```
>>> diff(f, x)
−sin(x)
```

An overview of the possible functions is given in the [online documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/index.html). It is free software and has quite readable source code.

Comment: Can you pass some arguments to the `series` function so it shows up the higher order terms as well?

Comment: @Bolt64: I added an argument to the `series` function to show higher order terms.

Answer (score 8):

I recomend [MAXIMA](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/). Of home page of this CAS we have the apresentation

> "Maxima is a system for the manipulation of symbolic and numerical
>   expressions, including differentiation, integration, Taylor series,
>   Laplace transforms, ordinary differential equations, systems of linear
>   equations, polynomials, and sets, lists, vectors, matrices, and
>   tensors. Maxima yields high precision numeric results by using exact
>   fractions, arbitrary precision integers, and variable precision
>   floating point numbers. Maxima can plot functions and data in two and
>   three dimensions."

Comment: MAXIMA is also a [component](http://www.sagemath.org/links-components.html) of Sage.

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) which is a system for computational discrete algebra, with particular emphasis on Computational Group Theory. Sometimes, I really can't go further without using it while solving and guessing the desired results in Group theory problems. Try it. It makes you feeling better. :)

Comment: Note that GAP comes as a [component](http://www.sagemath.org/links-components.html) of Sage.

Comment: @Pece: I didn't know that really. Thanks for remarking the point.

Answer (score 7):

Numpy, scipy and matplotlib are amazing packages in Python. They basically handle all kinds of numerical analysis and basically replace matlab.

Answer (score 6):

I know Octave and Freemat, both claim similarity to Matlab but I don't have first hand experience on them. [This article](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~gobbert/papers/SharmaGobbertTR2010.pdf)  compares Matlab, Octave, Scilab and Freemat. The source is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523803/freemat-how-different-is-it-from-octave) MO question answer of which may be of some help.

Comment: And qtoctave adds a GUI similar to Matlab’s as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/faq.html). SAGE includes this as a component too, but I really like GP alone, as it is. In fact, GP comes with integer relation finding functions (as you mentioned) and has enough rational/series symbolic power that I have been able to implement Sister Celine's method for finding recurrence relations among hypergeometric sums in GP with ease.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to deal with multivariate polynomial rings, [Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/index.php) and [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/) come to mind. I have not  tried the software much, but I definitely would in cases like the above.

Comment: sage also allows you to work with [polynomial rings](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/tour_polynomial.html)

Comment: @ohn C: Thanks for the link. I have not been aware of the fact that some of Sage's multivariate polynomial functions are attributed to Singular.

Answer (score 1):

I really think that [DataMelt scientific computational environment](http://jwork.org/dmelt/) is among solid alternative's of Mathematica. First, it's free. Second, it's Java and runs on Linux, Mac and Windows. It has everything that Mathematica has, namely:

- Function plotting in 2D and 3D Histogramming in 2D and 3D Data
- analysis  Statistical packages (regression, non-linear fits)
- Symbolic computations with a number of Java engines
- Calculations with physics/measurements units
- Very strong IO (some based on Java serialisation)
- Very good IDE with Help assist
- Very detailed manual about 300 examples and a book
- A number of languages are supported (Python, Groovy, Java, Ruby) You can mix programming with high-level math calculations