# Efficient free alternative to *Mathematica*

Tags: calculus, soft-question, math-software, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics

I am searching for a free alternative to *Mathematica*. By efficient, I mean that it should have every (or at least almost every) function that you can find in *Mathematica*, including for example **Number Recognition**. Also, if you know such software, can you post a reference manual for usage here as well?

Comment: I don't think you'll find freeware with almost every function that you find in Mathematica. What are you trying to do specifically? Does something simple like Wolfram Alpha work? If you're enrolled in a university, chances are you can get some great software for free. Also, you my want to ask this question on the Mathematica Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm looking for a free alternative to a Ferrari. By efficient, I mean it should do everything the Ferrari does - but be free. Also, please post the user manual here. Like omg thanks.

Comment: @Dal: Some have tried (Maxima and Mathics), but will not get close (V10 just came out recently). However, there are many wonderful free CASes (SAGE is an amalgamation of many very nice ones and very powerful), see the list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems.

Comment: You might be interested in answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/391224/73025).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) from MIT? It's under GNU-license.

Comment: Does it work well from your point of view?

Comment: @Dal: I'm to old to start learn that kind of programs because it would take too much time from other things I would like to do. But I have looked at it and it seems to be very comprehensive and advanced (for example in algebra).

Comment: Good. I'll try it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.